Contains more than one active subscription. First one willbe selected for further use. To select another subsctiption use set-azcontext
Im getting below errror while running the pipeline
Contains more than one active subscription. First one willbe selected for further use. To select another subsctiption use set-azcontext
I have tried multiple ways but still im unable to resolve my issue . Could anyone help me here please
I tried making changes in script but that wwrning before script is being called

First of all, the message is a warning rather than an error. I can reproduce the issue when the underlying service principal (app registration) that the Azure Resource Manager service connection referenced by the AzurePowerShell pipeline task is assigned with RBAC roles (like contributor or owner etc.) in the scopes of multiple subscriptions.

You may find the service principal and check its role assignments across subscriptions following the marks in the image below.

We can easily set multiple subscriptions with Set-AzContext command in one single the AzurePowerShell secession.
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  subX: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
  sub8: yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMSvcCnnWIFRootOwner'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      Write-Host "================ Switch to subX ================"
      Set-AzContext -subscription "$(subX)"
     
      Write-Host "================ Switch to sub8 ================"
      Set-AzContext -subscription "$(sub8)"
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'


